# How to populate QTableWidget via plugin?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qt-designer

I am attempting to populate a QTableWidget by adding rows, this is done by the user clicking on the `add` button:

[image: QTableWidget]

I have the following code to try and insert rows but nothing is happening:

```
def addButton_clicked():
    # objectName for add button = addButton
    # objectName for QTableWidget = tableWidget
    model = dockwidget.tableWidget
    rowCount = self.model.rowCount()
    self.model.insertRows(rowCount, 1)

add_button = self.dockwidget.addButton
add_button.clicked.connect(addButton_clicked)
```

---

The `Group` and `Order` columns were created from Qt Designer. I am trying to create rows in which the user can select a group from the ToC (in the `Group` column) and assign an integer (in the `Order` column). Is something like this possible?

I am open to other ideas.

---

The following code from @WKT creates a table with columns and x number of rows. I can populate the table with the names of the groups in the ToC. **However, I only want to populate the first column**. The code I run at the moment populates all columns. Here is the code:

```
qTable = self.dockwidget.tableWidget
data = []
group1 = root.findGroup('Group1')
group2 = root.findGroup('Group2')
for child in group1.children():
    data.append(child.name())
for child in group2.children():
    data.append(child.name())
nb_row = len(data)
nb_col = 2
qTable.setRowCount(nb_row)
qTable.setColumnCount(nb_col)

for row in range(nb_row):
    for col in range(nb_col):
        item = QTableWidgetItem(str(data[row]))
        qTable.setItem(row,col,item)

qTable.setHorizontalHeaderLabels([u'Column1',u'Column2'])
qTable.resizeColumnsToContents()
```

[image: QTableWidget]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let me share how it works for me:

```
self.setWindowTitle(title)

#data = 'Recordset back from postgis'
nb_row = len(data)
nb_col = 2

qTable.setRowCount(nb_row)
qTable.setColumnCount(nb_col)

for row in range (nb_row):
    for col in range(nb_col):
        item = QTableWidgetItem(str(data[row][col]))
        qTable.setItem(row,col,item)

qTable.setHorizontalHeaderLabels([u'Column1',u'Column2'])

qTable.resizeColumnsToContents()
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing, so you basically just immediately populate the table with rows/columns? I will come back to this in a couple of days and let you know how I get on :)

Comment: I use it in a generic Dialog to show results of a DB query and let the user pick a row. Run fine. Any problem, let us know....

Comment: Yes, sorry you are correct. Tried to delete the comment before you could read it ;).

Comment: Thank you, got it working. The last hurdle is to populate the first column with a set of group names from the ToC. I've updated my question =)

Comment: Not sure to understand but I think that the "data" var need, in your case, to look like [["group1", "child1"],["group1", "child2",[etc...]...

Comment: Just needed to change `for col in range(nb_col):` to `for col in [0]:`. Many thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

Found a way, basically you just need to specify the column when populating the QTableWidget (mentioned in comment):

```
qTable = self.dockwidget.tableWidget
data = []
group1 = root.findGroup('Group1')
group2 = root.findGroup('Group2')
for child in group1.children():
    data.append(child.name())
for child in group2.children():
    data.append(child.name())
nb_row = len(data)
nb_col = 2
qTable.setRowCount(nb_row)
qTable.setColumnCount(nb_col)

for row in range(nb_row):
    # Add following line to only populate first column
    for col in [0]:
        item = QTableWidgetItem(str(data[row]))
        qTable.setItem(row,col,item)

qTable.setHorizontalHeaderLabels([u'Column1',u'Column2'])
qTable.resizeColumnsToContents()
```

[image: QTableWidget]

Comment: I am doing an exact same thing with my plugin. Can you help me to know, on which file and method of the plugin I should include this code to ?